# I want to get the values of all the checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type = "checkbox"]').change(function() { //when a checkbox is checked
        var nvalues = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get();
        if (nvalues.length > 0) {
            var fin = nvalues.value;
            $('#here').html(fin);
        } else {
            $('#here').html("WTF");
        }
    });
});
```

here I'am storing the checked values as array using map but the output is empty.

Comment: i dont know if its because of that selector can you try doing it `$('input[type=checkbox]')`

Comment: if i select the 1st checkbox iam not getting the values of other selected box it is ging the value of only one checkbox like is 1 selected then it is showing iam 1 and if i then select 2 then it it shows iam 1 iwant to print if 1 and 2 selected then it show iam1 iam2

Answer (score 2):

See Comments in code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':checkbox').change(function() { // :checkbox pseudo-selector selects all checkboxes
        var nvalues = []; // Initialize empty array

        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function() { // For all checked checkboxes
            nvalues.push($(this).val()); // Push current checkbox value in array
        });


        if (nvalues.length > 0) {
            $('#here').html(nvalues.toString()); // Array to string conversion
        } else {
            $('#here').html("WTF");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The **[`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)** method will return an array of values , join them using **[`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** and then show it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type = "checkbox"]').change(function() { //when a checkbox is checked
        var nvalues = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get();
        if (nvalues.length > 0) {
            var fin = nvalues.join(',');
            $('#here').html(fin);
        } else {
            $('#here').html("WTF");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="3"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="4"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="5"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="6"/>
<div id="here"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type = "checkbox"]').change(function() { //when a checkbox is checked
        var nvalues = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();
        if (nvalues.length > 0) {
            var fin = nvalues[0];
            $('#here').html(fin);
        } else {
            $('#here').html("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There no is property in array like `value`:

```
var fin = nvalues.value;
```

Try join:

```
var fin = nvalues.join(','); //gives csv
```

OR

```
var fin = nvalues.join(' ');//spaces
```